# How to group Rails ActiveRecord results by a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a little time tracking application and ran into a problem I don't know how to solve. I have a `Task` model and a `Client` model. Each task belongs to a client.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  attr_accessible :client_id, :description, :start, :end

  scope :yesterday, -> {
    where('start > ?', Date.yesterday.to_time).where('start < ?', Date.today.to_time)
  }
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Right now I'm displaying a list of tasks scoped by the day the tasks were completed, and ordered by the time they were completed. I would like to display that same list, but grouped by the client, and sorted by the client name. Here's what I would like to do:

```
<div id="yesterday_summary">
  <% @yesterday_clients.each do |client| %>
    <h2><%= client.name %></h2>
    <ul>
      <% client.tasks.each do |task| %>
        <li><%= task.description %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In my controller I currently have:

```
@tasks_yesterday = Task.yesterday
@yesterday_clients = group_tasks_by_client @tasks_yesterday
```

And in the `group_tasks_by_client` method, I have some pretty ugly code that isn't even working at the moment:

```
  def group_tasks_by_client(tasks)
    clients = []
    tasks.collect(&:client).each do |client|
      clients << {client.id => client} unless clients.has_key? client.id
    end
    clients_with_tasks = []
    clients.each do |client|
      c = Struct.new(:name, :tasks)
      cl = c.new(client.name, [])
      tasks.each do |task|
        cl.tasks << task if task.client_id = client.id
      end
      clients_with_tasks << cl
    end
    clients_with_tasks
  end
```

I'm sure there is a clean, simple, rails-way to do this but I'm not sure how. How can this be done?

Comment: Does the rails group_by http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month method help?

Comment: @Catfish That `group_by` method looks really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have the database do this for you like so:

```
@yesterdays_clients = Client.includes(:tasks).merge(Task.yesterday).order(:name)
```

Besides being cleaner, it's more efficient since it gets all your clients and tasks in one pass.  The original code was subject to N+1 queries because there was no eager loading.

BTW, you can make your scope simpler as well:

```
scope :yesterday, -> { where(:start => (Date.yesterday.to_time...Date.today.to_time)) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what `Client.includes(:tasks).merge(Task.yesterday)` is actually doing behind the scenes?

Comment: [`includes()`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) is used to eager load an association.  [`merge()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) is used to make modifications to the query using properties of other models.  As long as the other model has previously been included or joined in the query, it should resolve properly.